# Custom jQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone please help to rewrite / tidy up this?

```
// News Article Slideshow
var periodToChangeSlide = 5000;
var pp_slideshow = undefined;
var currentPage = 0;

$('#news-feature-img-wrap li').css('display', 'list-item').slice(1).css('display', 'none');
$('#news-items li:first').addClass('active');

$("#news-feature-wrap #news-items li").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    var toShow = $("#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li").eq(index);
    toShow.show();
    toShow.siblings().hide();
    currentPage = index;
    $.stopSlideshow();
});

$.startSlideshow = function () {
    if (typeof pp_slideshow == 'undefined') {
        pp_slideshow = setInterval($.startSlideshow, periodToChangeSlide);
    } else {
        $.changePage();
    }
}

$.stopSlideshow = function () {
    clearInterval(pp_slideshow);
    pp_slideshow = undefined;
}
$.changePage = function () {
    var numSlides = $('#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li').length;
    currentPage = (currentPage + 1) % numSlides;
    var menu = $('#news-feature-wrap #news-items li').eq(currentPage);
    menu.addClass('active');
    menu.siblings().removeClass('active');

    var toShow = $("#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li").eq(currentPage);
    toShow.show();
    toShow.siblings().hide();
}

$.startSlideshow();
```

Comment: It would be nice to have example html.

Comment: @JordyVialoux You should use `===` by default, and not `==`.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a few suggestions for you:

Wrap your entire thing in an IIFE, you don't need any external access to any of your vars.

```
;(function(){
   ...your code goes here
}());
```

Now your period to change slide isn't in the global name space.

You don't need to attach your `startSlideSnow` and `stopSlideShow` to the jQuery namespace (e.g. $.startSlideShow) you are just polluting jQuery's namespace which isn't goot.

Use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval`.  The `setTimeout` function will only run after its callback is done, `setInterval` runs at the interval no matter what, so you can run into some strange behavior.

Try to not repeat selectors, and use chaining:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
```

could become:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

You could optimize your selectors as well, remember jQuery goes right to left, so in a lot of cases you're getting all `li` items on the page and filtering those.  It might be a marginal speed boost doing $( 'selector' ).find( 'li' );.

There are a few more things you could do, like pluginize it, but these are the biggest things I see right away.

Answer (score 0):

Without HTML we could not do too much, but here is what I noticed right away.

I would definately use more of the chaining that is provided with jQuery.

```
$("#news-feature-wrap #news-items li").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    $("#news-feature-wrap #news-feature-img-wrap li").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    currentPage = index;
    $.stopSlideshow();
});
```

This is more so taking advantage of the chaining in jQuery. It will not change performance and is strictly aesthetic.